# Yii framework migrate

Tags: php, sql, yii, sql-update

So, basically what i want is to make a file that will make some changes to my database. I have to enter some data, but to be faster, I want to use the sql IN operator. So what I want should look something like this:

```
$this->update('basicInfo', array('regionId' => 1), 
'WHERE countyId IN (SELECT id FROM countyTable WHERE regionId = 1 )')
```

regionId should be set to 1 when the countyId is 3,6,7,9,4 and so on

I know this won't work but I don't know how to make it work and is it possible to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See CDbCommand where function doc](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/db/CDbCommand.php#L778) for more information about how to use sql 'in' criteria.

I would do it like this:

```
// retrieve county ids for regionId = 1
$dbConn         = $this->getDbConnection();
$countyTableIds = $dbConn->createCommand()
    ->select('id')
    ->from('countyTable')
    ->where('regionId = 1')
    ->queryAll();

// prepare condition as array. 
$condition = array('in', 'countyId', $countyTableIds);

// update
$this->update('basicInfo', array('regionId' => 1), $condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ANY clause

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET status = 'inactive'
  WHERE countyId = ANY (SELECT id FROM countyTable WHERE regionId = 1 )
```